# Form Validation Issue (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to restrict user to submit the form if he does not click on check box. All are working fine except Var Check.

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
var check = document.forms["myform"]["check"].value; 
if (check.checked == false) 
{
    alert ('Please Accept our Terms and Conditions ');
    return false;
}else {     
    return true;
}

}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try code :

```
function validateForm() {
   if (document.getElementById("check").checked == false) 
   {
     alert ('Please Accept our Terms and Conditions ');
     return false;
   }else {     
     return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan Nghiem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the id to select the checkbox.
Look at this link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp

Example

```
//Find out if a checkbox is checked or not:

var x = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked;

//The result of x will be:

false or true
```

Answer (score 0):

your input checkbox must have id="checkbox"

```
 <form action="youraction" method="POST/GET" onSubmit="return validateForm();">
   .....
 </form>

function validateForm() {
 if(document.getElementById("checkbox").checked)
    return true;
 else 
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong:

```
var check = document.forms["myform"]["check"].value;
//it gives string value of checkbox
//string variable cannot refer to check-box state
```

```js
var chk = document.myform.check; //checkbox

var validate = function() {
  var errors = []; //list of errors, in-case you have few more field to validate
  if (!chk.checked) {
    errors.push('You must accept the terms & conditions');
  }
  //do the rest of the validations
  if (errors.length) {
    alert(errors.join('\n')); //show all errors here
  }
  return !errors.length; //don't submit if errors
};
```

```html
<form name='myform' onsubmit='return validate()'><!-- validate on submit -->
  <input type='checkbox' name='check' />I accept terms &amp; conditions
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
```